# How to completely buy out a domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I know that we can get a domain name on rent through many websites but can you tell me how can I completely buy a domain so that I don't have to pay the rent each year.

I own a domain  and I bought it for a year at $1.5 but I recently received an email about renewing my domain saying that to renew it again I have to pay almost $11 which is almost 10 times what I paid initially. Is there a way through which I can completely buy the domainname ? I'm sure there is a way because I dont think website like Facebook, Google pays rent for their domain each year.

Comment: Actually, they _do_ pay for their domain names every year.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I read somewhere that Facebook bought its domain for $200,000. So are they paying$200,00 every year ?

Comment: `whois facebook.com` says that it currently expires 2020-03-29T21:00:00-0700.  I have no idea what you read, but they've only prepaid their domain registration for another five years.

Comment: @MadHatter seems scary that you cant buy the domain. Thanks for the info

Comment: You can spend a lot of money to get a domain that is already registered to someone else - if you really want that name. But once it's registered in your name you pay the same renewal fees as everyone else. Most registrars allow you to register/renew domains for up to 10 years (not sure if that is the limit?).

Comment: @w3d Not sure if they still have that, but Network Solutions used to offer 100-year registrations. It wasn't a true 100-year registration: you paid up front, they would register the domain name for as long as possible (usually ten years), then promised to keep renewing it for the full 100-year period. This of course assumes that Network Solutions will remain in business for the next century...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way through which I can completely buy the domainname ?

No.

> I'm sure there is a way because I dont think website like Facebook, Google pays rent for their domain each year.

[Yes, they do.](http://www.businessinsider.com/this-guy-bought-googlecom-from-google-for-one-minute-2015-9)

Comment: yeah i read the article but it also said that there was a technical glitch and moreover it he way able to buy the domain for $12 then why was he forced to submit the domain name?

Comment: He didn't "buy" it in the sense that he owned it forever. He bought it for a year and had the rights to use it just like any other domain purchase. And if you Google it you will find other examples of large companies who forgot to renew their domain name and temporarily lost it. They have to play by the same rules as everyone. No one gets special treatment.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm sure it would be a nightmare if a company forgets to renew it

Comment: And there was [the time when Microsoft forgot to renew hotmail.co.uk](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2003/11/06/microsoft_forgets_to_renew_hotmail/)!